# Подслушать COM порт Windows 7x64. Python win32api

Tags: python, com-порт

Необходимо параллельно с приложением Windows, которое читает COM порт, забирать данные с этого же порта, желательно, используя не ниже python3.8.
Поскольку, похоже, что pyserial работает через win32api, я делаю следующее (не используя pyserial):

```py
import win32file

com_file = win32file.CreateFile("COM4",
                                win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                                win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32file.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                None,
                                win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                                win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)
com_dcb = win32file.DCB()
com_dcb.ByteSize = 8
com_dcb.Parity = win32file.NOPARITY
com_dcb.StopBits = win32file.ONESTOPBIT
com_dcb.BaudRate = 9600
win32file.SetCommState(com_file, com_dcb)
win32file.SetCommMask(com_file, win32file.EV_RXCHAR | win32file.EV_TXEMPTY)
win32file.SetupComm(com_file, 1024, 1024)

while True:
    win32file.WaitCommEvent(com_file, None)
    output = win32file.ReadFile(com_file, 14)
    print(output)
```

то есть, я указываю параметр **shareMode** = **win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32file.FILE_SHARE_DELETE**, про который написано [тут](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__CreateFile_meth.html), но при последующем запуске другого приложения, оно не может получить доступ к COM порту - порт занят.
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли вообще через win32api реализовать подслушивание COM порта?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вообще-то нет. Вы попробуйте сначала запустить другое приложение, а потом ваше, у вас порт тоже не откроется. Есть вариант, если порт виртуальный, то драйвер уровня ядра может прослушать данные usb. Для этого есть специальные программы, например, Device Monitoring Studio. И она точно работает не на winapi, она использует свой драйвер. Средствами winapi это не сделать.

Comment: Portmon(32bit), accessport(64) используют свой драйвер-прослойку. Ещё можно посмотреть, как работает `com0com`

Comment: да, я пробовал другим софтом мониторить порт, и они работают. Если я не ошибаюсь, COM Port Toolkit 4.0 и Advanced Serial Port Monitor выдавали данные параллельно, но это уже не важно. Теперь понятно, что win32api тут не спасёт, и shareMode параметр только ввёл меня в заблуждение. Спасибо за комментарии!